# Can we add previous and next arrow in the Lwc lightning-carousel tag for image slider?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, lightning-components

I am trying to build component that has lighting carousel tag and which has image slider in it but I wanted to add arrow buttons of previous and next button for manual control over the slider.

Comment: We only managed to do it by manually drawing buttons next to the carousel, which worked but my PO hated it so I don't have any code to show you